# virtualhost with nginx and Apache

Tags: apache, nginx

I have set up my local machine with nginx and apache. I use nginx as a frontend-server for all nodejs communication. Every nodejs application has an own upstream defined and an entry in my hosts file, so that I get a handy URL to work with. Also, i have one upstream defined for apache, which works on port 8080 in my config - so that all my php applications are available under localhost/* (internally it is localhost:8080/*). This configuration is working fine for several month now. But this time I would like to set up a magento installation on my local machine. For this purpose I added `127.0.0.1 magento.local`to my hosts file (like I did for all nodejs applications) and added the following to my nginx.conf:

```
upstream apache {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  magento.local;
    client_max_body_size    1024M;
    root /Users/phunkei/htdocs/magento;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://apache;
    }
}
```

This rewrites everything to `/Users/phunkei/htdocs/`, which is my root for apache. I already tried to add a subfolder to the upstream definition `server 127.0.0.1:8080/magento`, but nginx does not allow that.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But the `root` statement is redundant. It is not required and is not used. Are you trying to do `proxy_pass http://apache/magneto/;`?

Comment: Yes, it will will add "magento" to the url, resulting in `http://magento.local/magento`. I'm trying to let `http://magento.local/`point to `/Users/phunkei/htdocs/magento` or `http://localhost:8080/magento`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you proxy everything, so `http://magento.local/` points to `http://localhost:8080/`.

If you want `http://magento.local/` to point to `http://localhost:8080/magento/` you need to use:

```
proxy_pass http://apache/magneto/;
```

If you want to serve some static content directly from `nginx` using your `root /Users/phunkei/htdocs/magento`, you will need to add directives to achieve that, such as moving the proxy code into a named location and using `try_files`:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
```

Comment: I already tried `proxy_pass http://apache/magento/;`, but it results in a 302 redirect to `http://localhost/magento/`

Comment: That 302 looks like it is coming from `apache` not from `nginx`. What does the apache access log say?